# Is it better to use session_set_save_handler?

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

Is is better to use session_set_save_handler and set our own mechanism or let PHP handle it?
If yes/no why?
I do not want to store the session in a DB because of the overhead in Input/output.
I am thinking of using memcache for storing the sessions.

Comment: **It depends.** Is the regular session handler not sufficient for your purposes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use memcached as a session store, you just need to [change the `session.save_handler` configuration to `memcached`](http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.sessions.php) for that to work automatically. Other extensions may offer similar predefined session handlers.

If there's no session handler that you like, you can create your own and register it using `session_set_save_handler`. Otherwise, don't reinvent the wheel.